# ADO.NET (ODP.NET) and same Connection pool for different clients connection

Tags: oracle, ado.net

We have to implement a two tier architecture to distribute a cache from a central Oracle DB to a lot of clients (circa 200) into an Intranet. After some experimentations we have opted to use a direct connection from the client to the DB server. This decision has been taken to simplify the architecture and to reduce the overheads.

Client application are made in C# and the natural choice should be to adopt ODP.NET (ADO).

But now we are trying to understand **if it is possible to have and to use the same connection pool for all the clients connection**. The clients will connect with the same functional username and password.

Could anyone help me in clarifying this key point?

Comment: can you post your connection string format? Also, for ODP.net, i assume every client will have the Oracle Instant Client installed?

Comment: What do you mean for Oracle Instant Client? I assume that our application will use an OCI Assembly that is the native driver in managed code to Oracle. I will not have to deploy any other packages, only the OCI assembly with the main application.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the ODP.net data provider depends on having the oracle instant client installed on the client location! Refer point 3 - Dependency Information here http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/windows/odpnet/odac11.1.0.6.21_ic_readme.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered looking at Oracle 11g Database Resident Connection Pooling?  This may resolve your issue.

Comment: +1 Adding the link....http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/DatabaseResidentConnectionPool_11gR1.php